# Trying to Fix MBR

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

I first decided that I wouldn't need Windows anymore, so I deleted it when I installed Ubuntu (I realized how wrong I was: no visual studio nor texnic center). Now I tried getting Windows back, so I reinstalled Windows using the recovery image. Now the Grub boot is stuck, and I can't get the windows bootloader. Googling shows that you can use a Windows 7 disk to get it back for a Windows 7 PC. I don't have the 7 disk but I do have the windows 8 disk. Would it still work?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? The MBR is essentially the same for all BIOS versions of Windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader Not sure about UEFI.

Comment: worth trying https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm sure my computer uses BIOS. So I'm guessing it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows 7 boot repair disk can be [safely downloaded from the Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38435).

Boot that and use the boot repair from that to repair your boot loader.

I *would not* use a Windows 8 boot repair disk to repair Windows 7 (this is not Linux)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Wow.. I didn't know the the repair disk link even existed. However, I used the Windows 8 disk a couple days back, since I read that the MBR for 8 and 7 are the same. My computer is now back to normal, but thanks anyways.